# C# Display JPG Image with WPF doesn't work

Tags: c#, image, xaml

For a project, i have to display a JPG photo without Data Binding, and without using source into the XAML file. To do this, i would like to use  this function :

```
private void updatephoto(string urlphoto)
{
   photo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("{0}", urlphoto), UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Because my teacher use it in his example, and for him it works !!
My class is composed like that (it's an excerpt) :

```
class Recette
{
    public String photo { get; private set; }
}
```

With a constructor that admit a String for a Relative Path. Using the relative path works fine in the XAML file with the Source="nameoffile.jpg" but when in my MainWindows.xaml.cs I want to display the photo using this :

```
Recette selectedRecette;
void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   selectedRecette = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as Recette;
   updatephoto(selectedRecette.photo);
}
```

The last line call the :

```
     private void updatephoto(string urlphoto)
     {
         photo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(String.Format("{0}", urlphoto), UriKind.Relative));
     }
```

In the XAML the image is :

```
< Image Height="100" Name="photo" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/ >
```

So I don't understand why this doesn't work

Comment: In what way does it not work? Be more specific

Comment: Nothing appear when i "compile", it's blank, but if i put directly Source="namephoto.jpg" in the XAML code, i can see the photo normally :/

Comment: Does it work if you hardcode the string in "Update photo"? Could the data you are getting out of the combo box be junk?

Comment: The data is correct, i have display it in a textbox, it's the good name of file, if i hardcode the string directly in updatephoto, it doesn't work too :( any other idea ? If you prefer i can take screenshots of my windows or upload the project or maybe Teamviewer/Skype if a person prefer and have time :/ ?

Comment: You have plenty of information, just trying to fill in a few gaps. If you have access to your instructors sample, have you checked the relative paths are the same, that the file actually is accessible via the relative path? Does an absolute path work?

Comment: Yes, when i put a full path like : photo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\projetf - Copie\td6bis\flamby.jpg")); It's Working, the photo appear, but i can't put a full path in a String variable because of the "\" :/ so i need to have a relative path no ?

Comment: You can use either (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said an absolute path worked, which is great! Your code works *exactly* as expected.

You can always use absolute paths, the statement:

```
String path = @"C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\projetf - Copie\td6bis\flamby.jpg";
```

**Is totally valid** because of the "@" symbol. It says the entire string is a **string literal** and so the '\' character does not escape anything.

If you really need relative paths, its likely the path doesn't point where you think it does. The key is that all relative paths are relative to the *working directory of the executable*. This is normally the folder the executable resides in, but there are places it gets weird.

A quick primer on relative paths:

1. If your path is just a filename (ie. "test.jpg") the file needs to be located in the executing directory.
2. If the path looks like a normal path (ie. @"Images\test.jpg") then it is looking for a folder called "Images" in the executing directory that contains the image file.
3. If you have dots, then its going "up" the directory tree (ie. @"..\Images\test.jpg"). This goes up a directory from the executing directory, looks for a folder called "Images" and looks for the image file there.

Totally random information; the statement `String.Format({0}, "MySTring")` does the same thing as `"MySTring"`. There is no reason for the String.Format if you only have one argument, and that argument is the entire string.

Comment: Thank you ! So i will put the full path ! ^^ My files are in the executing directory it was because i'm questioning me :( and using relative path in the XAML file as source work ! But not in the C#... It's strange ! So i will use the full path thanks ! ^^

Comment: Nothing wrong with relative paths, just make sure they point to where the file is actually at (its very easy to mess this up). Absolute paths are much safer but (obviously) much more verbose. Absolute paths also carry the problem that they may not work on another computer (unless he puts your app into the same directory structure you have).

Comment: @Playzare, Just to make you aware of a feature on StackOverflow, when you feel you have a good answer (feel free to wait awhile to make sure no more come in!) you can click the green check mark next to the answer you feel helped you the most to "accept it". This tells the community what helped you the most and provides you and the answerer with some reputation (of course there is no obligation to do this, just making sure you know about it!).

Comment: Thank you ! I have check your answer because you have helped me a lot ! Thanks, if i did this wrong tell me because i don't know if it's correctly check :)

Comment: @Playzare, The check "fills" (and remains so after leaving hover) when you have accepted it. You'll also see a +2 to your reputation for accepting an answer. You can learn more about how to use StackOverlow by visiting the help: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and the meta site. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you ! But like i'm french it's hard to understand everything ^^' Thanks, good day to you !